# Want to understand the epsilon-delta definition of a limit, please help me!

Tags: limits

I completely don't  understand the epsilon-delta definition of a limit, could please someone help me with more clarifications?

Thank you.

Comment: clear your mind considering two cases: limit of sequences and limits of functions

Comment: hmmm... what do you mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mathematical problem that your boss wants you to do, but it's expensive to get a *perfectly* accurate answer, so you'll have to approximate. The boss tells you to approximate it within an error tolerance of $.01$, and you do it. The boss then wants it to an error tolerance of $.0001$, so you do it; this time, it's harder, because you have a lower tolerance. The boss still isn't happy, so he has you do it for $.0000001$. This time, it takes even longer.

The errors are your $\epsilon$, and the amount of effort you have to put in is like your $\delta$: $\delta$ tells you how close you have to be to a point to make *sure* that the error is within your tolerance $\epsilon$. We say that a limit exists if for *any* tolerance $\epsilon$, you can find a $\delta$ corresponding to it. That is, with enough work, we can get as close as we want to the limit.

This is perfectly analogous to the $\epsilon-N$ definition for sequences.

Comment: Well explained!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we want $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)=L$. The idea is that you pick an $\varepsilon>0$, and I need to show that $f$ does indeed get within $\varepsilon$ of $L$ when evaluated near $c$. I do this by telling you how close you have to be to $c$ in order to make sure that $f(x)$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $L$. This is the $\delta>0$ part - I tell you that if $0<|x-c|<\delta$ (i.e. $x$ is within $\delta$ of $c$ and $x\ne c$), then I can guarantee $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$ (i.e. $f(x)$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $L$). Note that once you have a $\delta$ value that works, then any smaller $\delta>0$ also works. Also, $\delta$ depends on the particular value of $\varepsilon$ that you pick; some people choose to write $\delta_\varepsilon$.

Here's how it works with the intuitive idea of the limit, which is that $f(x)$ has to get very close to $L$ as $x$ gets close to $c$: The $f(x)$ being close to $L$ is formalized as $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon>0$. Finding a $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-c|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$ means that as $x$ gets within $\delta$ of $c$ (close to $c$), then $f(x)$ is indeed very close to $L$.